# Setup Ember.js with Typescript

Tags: ember.js, typescript

I'm trying to set up Ember.js with Typescript, so what i did is downloading the declaration file from the DefinitelyTyped repository (and also those for handlebars, ...).

But without having coded a single line i get a lot of errors, 84 to be more precisely, concerning the the ember.d.ts file.

I also tried the jquery declaration file which worked quite well.

Is there anything i forgot to set up? Is the ember declaration file up working with the current version of Typescript?

Comment: There looks like there is a bit of a name clash in Ember - it defines an `Array` interface, but the TypeScript lib.d.ts has an `Array<T>` interface. That definition is going to take a bit of fixing. It also used `: Array;` as a type and to fix that it will need to be determined where it means the Ember `Array` type and where it means `any[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That definition file works fine with TypeScript 0.9.1. It has not been updated for TypeScript 0.9.5 and will give errors. Any help would be appreciated : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/1385#issuecomment-30489919

Comment: Thanks, thats what i thought.